# How to wait for confirm dialog inside angular ui sortable callback

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

I am using angular ui sortable to drag and drop items between lists. What I would like to be able to do is (under certain drag/drop conditions) have a confirm dialog and if the user cancels the dialog, then revert the lists back to their original state. I can use the `ui.item.sortable.cancel()` method inside the update event, but if I use a modal that returns a promise, I can't figure out how to revert the lists on cancel. Here is what I have in my controller (modalService is a bootstrap $uibModal):

```
$scope.sortableOptions =
        handle: ' > span > span > .task-drag-icon',
        connectWith: ".task-subset"
        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        update: (e, ui) ->
          if ui.item.sortable.sourceModel == ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel #sort was within the same list
            #some other logic here.....
          else
            droptarget_element = ui.item.sortable.droptarget

            if droptarget_element.attr('ng-model') == "task.subTasks"
              #need the user to confirm here if they really want to do this drag/drop
              modalOptions =
                closeButtonText: 'Cancel'
                actionButtonText: 'Make SubTask'
                headerText: 'Make SubTask?'
                bodyText: 'This action will remove any existing task groups as it will become a child task. Is this OK?'
              modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then (result) ->
                  console.log "accpted"
                , () ->
                  console.log "cancelled"
                  #need to call ui.item.sortable.cancel() here, but I cant because the update callback has finished already!!!!

              console.log "finished - gets to here immediately as modalService is asyncronous"

          return
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get this working without some major hacks, so instead I ended up not using the cancel() method in the update callback, but just reverting the data in the appropriate arrays back to how they were in eth stop callback, by assigning some variables like so:

```
    $scope.sortableOptions =
        handle: ' > span > span > .task-drag-icon',
        connectWith: ".task-subset"
        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        stop: (e, ui) ->
          orig_index = ui.item.sortable.index
          new_idex = ui.item.sortable.dropindex
          sourceModel = ui.item.sortable.sourceModel
          droptargetModel = ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel
          model = ui.item.sortable.model

          if sourceModel == droptargetModel #sort was within the same list
            #some other logic here.....
          else
            droptarget_element = ui.item.sortable.droptarget

            if droptarget_element.attr('ng-model') == "task.subTasks"
              #need the user to confirm here if they really want to do this drag/drop
              modalOptions =
                closeButtonText: 'Cancel'
                actionButtonText: 'Make SubTask'
                headerText: 'Make SubTask?'
                bodyText: 'This action will remove any existing task groups as it will become a child task. Is this OK?'
              modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then (result) ->
                  console.log "accpted"
                , () ->
                  #put model back in orginal poisition
                  sourceModel.splice orig_index, 0, model
                  #remove from target array
                  droptargetModel.splice new_idex, 1

          return
```